# What is wrong with my Touchpad Driver installation in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, touchpad

> **FYI** : I used Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and Acer TravelMate P243-M Notebook.

I wanted to activate scrolling feature on my Touchpad Notebook, then i installed the Touchpad Driver from its manufacture.

I saw in Acer's website that they didn't provide Drivers for Windows 10 yet. So, i installed the latest one that available over there which was Touchpad Driver for Windows 8 64-bit.

The problem is `i've activated scrolling feature on mouse's setting and also restarted my notebook, but it still didn't worked for me`.

[image: configuration of my mouse]

Anyone can help me, please ??

Comment: Drivers for previous versions of Windows isn't guaranteed to work, just because the software installed, doesn't mean the driver is compatible with Windows 10

Comment: This Acer Community page regards your problem [link](http://community.acer.com/t5/Windows-10/touchpad-stopped-working-after-windows-10/td-p/372205).

Comment: @spike_66 .. i'll try it first. Thanks for that.